# Is there any support in .NET 3.5 to launch the application in a different language? Mainly strings (Menu items, prompt messages etc)

Tags: c#, xaml

If I am showing messagebox like:

```
Messagebox.show("Please add a point!", "Title", messageboxbutton.ok, messageboxicon.info);
```

I want the strings to get changed in other language (chinese, german etc). I use XAML for UI and C# for code behind. I tried using `sisulizer` but could not translate even a single string, any support on using `sisulizer` will also be helpful.

I can provide additional info if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using rather simple words and sentences, I suggest you use Google Translate do make the translations. Keep the translated data in separate resource-files for each language and use them accordingly. Here's an easy introduction to using resource files in WPF:

- [**Localize WPF application with resource files**](http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/localize-wpf-application-with-resource-files/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Sisulizer or any other localization tool you must first internationalize your application. This means that you prepare your code to work on any language and you remove hard coded strings (e.g. "Please add a point!") with resource strings.

Add the two strings from you message box into a .resx file. Each item in .rexs will have a correspodning ID. For examle

```
Properties.Resources.Please is for "Please add a point!"
Properties.Resources.Title is for "Title"
```

Finally modify you source code

```
Messagebox.showProperties.Resources.Please, Properties.Resources.Title, messageboxbutton.ok, messageboxicon.info);
```